# Using Robotium, how do I verify that video is starting?

Tags: android, robotium

How do I verify that video is starting and not showing a black screen? The video starts automatically, when the page shows.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer myself. Cast the view to VideoView and use the isplaying() method to check.